# The vertices of an undirected graph are numbered 1,2,...4286. The edge (i,j) exists if |i-j| <= 3, where i!=j. Which statements are true?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, hamiltonian-cycle

The vertices of an undirected graph are numbered 1,2,...4286. The edge (i,j) exists if |i-j| <= 3, where i!=j. Which statements are true?

- the graph contains an Eulerian circle
- the graph contains a perfect matching graph
- the graph is Hamiltonian

I'm thinking that the last two are true, while the first one is false.
Is this correct?

Comment: Why do you think that? Please explain your rationale, so answerers can help you better by correcting your mistake (if there are such).

Comment: All vertices need to have an even degree for it to be an Eulerian circle and vertex 1 has the degree 3, so it isn't an Eulerian circle.  This is the only one I'm sure of. The other two are more based on intuition. For it to be a Hamiltonian graph I think you can go from even vertex to even vertex, then return from odd vertex to odd vertex @amit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph is not an [Eulerian cycle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerianCycle.html) since such a cycle requires that every node has an even degree, but in this graph, node 1 has an odd degree -- its neighbors are 2, 3 and 4.

The graph contains a [perfect matching](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectMatching.html): one possible match would be the collection of edges that connects  to +1, for each odd :

```
1─2, 3─4, 5─6, ... , 4285─4286
```

The graph is a [Hamiltonian graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonianGraph.html), as it contains the following Hamiltonian cycle:

```
1─2 ─ 4─5 ─ 7─8 ─ 10─11 ─ 13─14 ─ ...    ─ 4282─4283 ── 4285─4286   
 \                                                            /
  ─ 3 ─── 6 ─── 9 ──── 12 ──── ... ─── 4281 ─────── 4284 ─────
```

So at the bottom we have all multiples of 3, and at the top all the other values.

Comment: Thanks for the response! And if I had an odd number instead of an even number, then it would only be a Hamiltonian graph, right?